# filling the space between image and edge with text

Tags: html, css, media-queries

For this screen size the text div should be aligned to right and it should fill all the space between image and the edge.

The width of image is fixed, but text width is responsive.

For the smaller screen sizes the text div should be above image (it results from html in my code so I didn't add more media queries here)

http://jsfiddle.net/cqNDH/

HTML:

```
    <div id="galeria">
    <div class="gutter"></div>
    <div class="wrapper" id="m_col">
    <div id="content--pro">
        <a>previous</a>
        <a>next</a>
        <p>THIS IS TITTLE</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum </p>
        <a><p>a link</p></a>
    </div><div id="show" ><span id="img--pro"><span id="img--pro--inner"></span></span></div><div id="show" >
    <span style="background-color:green" id="img--pro"><span id="img--pro--inner"></span></span></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1151px) and (max-width: 1411px)  {
    #galeria{width:100%;height: 100%;margin:0 auto;}
    .gutter{display:inline-block;width:3%;height:100%;margin-bottom:10px;float:left;display: inline-block;}
    .wrapper{height:100%;width:94%;float:left;}

    #img--pro {display: inline-block;width: 100%;font-size: 0;line-height: 0;vertical-align: middle;    background-size: 100%;
        background-position: 50% 50%;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-color:blue;
    background-image: url('');}
    #img--pro--inner {display: block;height: 0;padding-top: 100%;}
    #show{width:760px;float:left;display:inline-block;}
    #content--pro{float:right;min-width:20px; max-width:300px; display:inline-block;background-color:yellow;}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no image in your example.

Comment: Yes, you can easily add images like this: `<img src="http://placehold.it/500X400" alt="text equivalent of image goes here">`

Comment: I thought it doesn't really matters. If you have the screen size between 1151px and 1411px it displays blue and green squares as the background, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

There was no image in your fiddle.

> For the smaller screen sizes the text div should be above image (it results from html in my code so I didn't add more media queries here)

The easiest way would be:

```
media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
 /* for example:
  * text can be added with a position absolute, 
  * and then use top: 0 to place it above in the container..
  */
}
```

This way you can send the text above the image.